# Is there a way to use complex types as SitecoreFields?

Tags: glass-mapper

Is there a way to use complex types to duplicate property declarations in a Glass model?

For example, imagine a page with 5 images on it and each image needs a URL and alt text:

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "..." )]
public class ImagePageGlassModel 
{
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Image 1 URL")]
    public virtual string Image1Url { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Image 1 Alt")]
    public virtual string Image1Alt{ get; set; }

    // repeat for 2, 3 and 4 ...

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Image 5 URL")]
    public virtual string Image5Url { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Image 5 Alt")]
    public virtual string Image5Alt{ get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to refactor this so that you have something like the following and still provide the 10 editable fields in the CMS:

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "..." )]
public class ImagePageGlassModel 
{       
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Image 1")]
    public virtual ImageGlassModel Image1 { get; set; }

    // repeat for 2, 3 and 4 ...

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Image 5")]
    public virtual ImageGlassModel Image5 { get; set; }
}

public class ImageGlassModel
{
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "URL")]
    public virtual string Image1Url { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Alt")]
    public virtual string Image1Alt{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I assume that you have defined 5 x 2 sets of fields on your template, as opposed to the items being linked (either in a multilist field or as child items)?

Comment: @jammykam Yes, I currently have 5x2 pairs of fields. I'd like to refine this to 5 fields of the `ImageGlassModel`.